# Need to write a reducer for adding an new idea element with multiple objects

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

Cant figure out how to add a new idea element with multiple page objects. Also when I add the new idea element with an unique id...I would also need to concat page objects to existing idea element. How would I filter using spread operator to check if the idea element exists then concat page objects else add new element?
Here's an example of my default data for structure:

```
    ideaID1: { 0:{title:'first', desc:'abc'}
        1:{title:'second', desc:'lmn'}
        2:{title:'third', desc:'pqr'}
      }
    ideaID2: { 0:{title:'first', desc:'abc'}
        1:{title:'second', desc:'pqr'}
        2:{title:'third', desc:'lmn'}
      }
```

I want to add the ideaID1(unique id) first and then will receive the 0, 1, 2 pages for that idea as and when the user will save the page. So I will need to concat those pages depending on which idea they belong to. Can somebody help me with the reducer using spread operator to add a new idea and then to add the pages to that idea element if it exists ..if not then create new?

I am receiving the following payload and written the following reducer

```
    {ideaID: 1, pagePostion: 0, title:'any', desc: 'abc'}

    {ideaID: 1, pagePostion: 1, title:'any', desc: 'per'}
    case 'ADD_IDEA': 
    return {
    ...state,
    [action.payload.ideaid]:{

        [action.payload.pagePosition]: [...action.payload]
}
  }
```

How would I concat the second payload and also check if the ideaID exists and then concat to it :

```
     return { ...state, { ...state[action.ideaid], 
     [action.payload.pagePosition]: [...action.payload] } }
```

Also what if ideaID is not found?

Comment: Please use arrays instead of array-like objects, unless it is absolutely justified to use the latter (not in this case, apparently).

Comment: Closer to the actual question, what code did you write that is not working? Can you please provide the code that doesn’t do what you want it to do?

Comment: I have updated my question with more info

Comment: how would I concat the second payload to the same ideaID

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using `lodash/fp`?
This will create maps / arrays if they don't exist.
You would need to use arrays for your pages, as advised in the comments.

```
import { set } from 'lodash/fp'

return set(
  [action.ideaid, action.payload.pagePosition],
  action.payload,
  state
)
```

https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc#_setpath-value-object